# Twilio get conference SID when connecting to devices

Tags: php, symfony, twilio

Is there a way to get the conference SID when connecting the calls in PHP?

```
$twilio->account->calls->create(
        $from,
        to,
        $twimlURL
    );
```

Can't I get the conference ID after this call action?
Or maybe set the conference SID on the Twiml. Is this possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you create a call through the REST API like that, it is not yet associated with a conference. I assume the `$twimlURL` that you send returns  `<Dial><Conference>some conference name</Conference></Dial>` and that is the time that the call is associated with the conference.

You can get the Conference SID by [listing conferences using the REST API and filtering by the `FriendlyName` (the name you used in the TwiML) and by the status `in-progress`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/conference#list-get). Like this:

```
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

$sid = "your_account_sid";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Client($sid, $token);

$conferences = $client->conferences->read(
    array("status" => "in-progress", "friendlyName" => "MyRoom")
);
foreach ($conferences as $conference) {
    echo $conference->sid;
}
```

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: It does. Thank you so much.

Comment: If it has helped you solve your problem, I'd really appreciate if you accept the answer as correct. That way anyone else with the same issue can see that this helped. Thanks!

Comment: don't really understand how do you get the conferenceSid if you need to send that param to the API itself (maybe the documentation on that link has been updated)

Comment: You list the conferences and filter by friendly name that you used in the `<Conference>` element.

Comment: friendlyName can be duplicate. I mean there can be another conference in progress at the same time with same friendlyName. How to tackle that issue?

Comment: There can only be one live conference with that friendlyName at a time. If you use `<Dial><Conference>friendlyName</Conference></Dial>` you will always be directed to that existing conference.

Answer (score 0):

In Case someone is looking for a C# version

```
  TwilioClient.Init(credentials.AccountSID, credentials.AuthToken);

  ResourceSet<ConferenceResource> conferencesResources = await ConferenceResource.ReadAsync(status: "in-progress", friendlyName: "<your conference room name>");

  ConferenceResource conference = conferencesResources.FirstOrDefault();

  Console.WriteLine(conference.Sid);
```